# Java security: how to ensure class is only access from specific package?

Tags: java

Now I know I can mark a method as 'no modifier' so that its only accessible by Class & Package.

That is not what I need in this case though. What I need is this:

Methods on Class "Secure.java" can only be accessed from other Classes in the same JAR file.

AND (this is extra)

When call is made into a secure method, the call stack does not go back to a none secure class & then back in again. For example:

This is good:

- com.nonsecure.ClassA.doStuff() calls
- com.nonsecure.ClassB.doStuff() calls
- com.secure.Secure.doStuff() calls
- com.secure.SecureB.doStuff()

This is bad:

- com.nonsecure.ClassA.doStuff() calls
- com.nonsecure.ClassB.doStuff() calls
- com.secure.Secure.doStuff() calls
- com.**nonsecure**.ClassC.doStuff() calls [BAD: we went outside the classes in the secure JAR!]
- com.secure.SecureB.doStuff()

---

Now I think I can do this via a little manual work:

```
 private void checkSecurity()
  {
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTraceElements)
    {
      // TODO: Add a little magic to check that we've not stepped outside the secure packages.
      if (!stackTraceElement.getClassName().startsWith("com.secure"))
      {
         throw new SecurityException("Woop!");
      }
    }
  }
```

QUESTION: This feels like there should be something that Java provides to help me out here?

I've read about

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>()
```

But seems to only be about accessing resources/network connections etc.
Not about accessing the call stack to ensure some sort of package protection.

Notes:

- I am using Spring 3
- The JAR file containing the secure code is signed
  with a certificate.
- Access to the secure class will only be from
  within the JAR, direct access from outside the JAR must not be
  allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Your title says 'from same package' which provides the hint. Put the class into the same package as the classes that may access it; don't make it public, so it is only accessible to classes in that package; sign the JAR file; and seal the package.

Comment: That would be find but there could be up to 700 classes that will need to use this SecureMap type object, and I don't really want to have 700 files in one package (+all their supporting classes).

Comment: @jeffporter You need to add that new constraint to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for access restrictions based on the container (jar) of your classes. Java does not provide such control on its own (at least not easily).

OSGI specifications are closer to the access control you want to achieve. In essence, OSGI do support and enforce access restrictions and rules based on the jar files (which it calls *bundles*).

You say you are using Spring: maybe have a look on these articles from JavaWorld [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2008/jw-04-osgi2.html) and [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html) to check in which extent OSGI can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can't use OSGI at the moment. But I might use that for a project later on!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the checkSecurity() method above.

I didn't find a Java 1.6 feature to help me out.